# Youtube API: VideoEntry update does not work

Tags: java, youtube-api

I use YouTube Java API and want to change privacy setting for uploaded video retrieved from feed [here](http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default/uploads)

This is how I tried to make video private:

```
XmlBlob xmlBlob = entry.getXmlBlob();
xmlBlob.setBlob("<yt:private/>");
entry.setXmlBlob(xmlBlob);
entry.update();
```

It's not working. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

OK,

I figured it out.

This is how you should set video to private:

```
private void setPrivateState(VideoEntry entry) throws Exception {
    YouTubeMediaGroup mediaGroup = entry.getMediaGroup();
    mediaGroup.setPrivate(true);
    entry.update();
}
```

and this is how you can set video to public:

```
private void setPublicState(VideoEntry entry) throws Exception {
    YouTubeMediaGroup mediaGroup = entry.getMediaGroup();
    if (mediaGroup.isPrivate()) {
        System.out.println("Video is private");
        mediaGroup.setPrivate(false);
    }

    XmlBlob entryBlob = entry.getXmlBlob();
    entryBlob.setBlob("<yt:accessControl action='list' permission='allowed'/>");
    entry.setXmlBlob(entryBlob);
    entry.update();
}
```

And this is how to set your video unlisted:

```
private void setUnlistedState(VideoEntry entry) throws Exception {
    YouTubeMediaGroup mediaGroup = entry.getMediaGroup();
    if (mediaGroup.isPrivate()) {
        System.out.println("Video is private");
        mediaGroup.setPrivate(false);
    }

    XmlBlob xmlBlob = entry.getXmlBlob();
    xmlBlob.setBlob("<yt:accessControl action='list' permission='denied'/>");
    entry.setXmlBlob(xmlBlob);
    entry.update();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest to use [YouTube Data API v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/), since it's the supported version. Then you can use recent [client libraries](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/libraries) and [examples](https://code.google.com/p/youtube-api-samples/source/browse/#git/samples).